# How to include resource ONLY on LOCAL/DEFAULT profile by using maven resources filtering?

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to use maven resource filtering to compile/package the `.jks` file **only at local**. Because of some reason, I can not include this file when I deploy the jar file on our cloud platform.

See, I have some resources files, located in `src/main/resources` folder, and these `.yaml` for different environments:

```bash
application.yaml
application-dev.yaml
application-uat.yaml
application-stg.yaml
application-prod.yaml
retruststore.jks
```

And this is part of `pom.xml` configuration:

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>default</id>
      <properties>
        <active.profile/>
      </properties>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>dev</id>
      <properties>
        <active.profile>dev</active.profile>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>uat</id>
      <properties>
        <active.profile>uat</active.profile>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <!-- some other profiles configured here... -->
    <!-- some other profiles configured here... -->
</profiles>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I write some pattern:

```xml
      <resources>
        <resource>
          <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
          <includes>
            <include>application.yaml</include>
            <include>retruststore.jks</include>
          </includes>
        </resource>

        <resource>
          <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
          <filtering>true</filtering>
          <includes>
            <include>application-${active.profile}.yaml</include>
          </includes>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>*.jks</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </resource>
      </resources>
```

When I execute `mvn compile` or IDE's `Build` I get these two files, that's good.

```bash
application.yaml
retruststore.jks
```

However, when I execute `mvn compile -P dev`, I still get the `.jks` file:

```bash
application.yaml
application-dev.yaml
retruststore.jks
```

What I expected when executing `mvn compile -P {env}`, I should get only `application-{env}.yaml` file.

How should I write the `<resources>` pattern to exclude this jks file when profile command effective?

Thank you!

Comment: `I can not include this file when I deploy the jar file on our cloud platform.` If you can not include it then remove from the `src/main/resources` directory ... and mixing spring boot profiles with Maven profiles is wrong...if you are in a cloud environment those configuration should be provided by the configuration services....

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for your comment. About the jks point, I'd like to explain more. Our project configured ssl in 'application.yaml' , so the jks is needed(because the sso need https protocol). But for our cloud container, ssl is no need. It seems got some internal mechanism can handle internal http to external https.

Comment: As I wrote packaging a configuration into a spring boot app which runs in a cloud environment is simply wrong... the configuration must be provided from outside (12 factor app see https://12factor.net/) also a JKS should not being part of your application it's something which is provided from outside as well as the JDK under which it is running...there should be a tool like Ansible, Terraform or alike to configure that ...

Comment: @khmarbaise Unfortunately, I cannot change more from now stage for our project. So I finally write some docker instructions to handle the file(s) which I don't want to include to DevOps. Anyway, thanks for your help, I've read the 12 factor app, that's a really great app design guide. Maybe I can practice it on next project.